# How to change text of button where the button is on list view?

Tags: android

```
private void shortlist(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>     () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("short response-------",response);
            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                btnSort.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF307668"));
                btnSort.setText("shortlisted");
                btnSort.setEnabled(false);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),matri_id_to, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_BY,matri_id_by);
            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_TO,matri_id_to);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

In this code we want to change text and color of button when the response is success otherwise text or color will same like before pressed but the button is on ListView

Comment: show us the output of `Log.e("short response-------",response);`

Comment: what is happening when you are executing your code of  `onSuccess()` .

Comment: when I clicked on button response was success but the text was not changed

Answer (score 0):

The main flow to change smth in `ListView` looks like:

- Keep the attribute (`success` in your case) inside your wrapper model which you use inside your adapter;
- Use this attribute inside you adapter to set proper style;
- Adjust model each time you want to change data (set `success` field of the proper entry);
- Call `notifyDataSetChanged` - your listView will be redrawn with proper status and proper state.

**BUT**

I really suggest you to use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead of ListView. The flow is almost the same but you could call `notifyItemChanged` to adjust only one entry (your button).

Comment: If i use RecyclerView so there is ViewHolder. with help of that we can change text or color.

Comment: @VKSGODIYAL If you use listView instead of recyclerView you should also use ViewHolder because it's more efficient patter than call 'expensive' findViewById. Viewholder is only to holding references to already found views.

Comment: Even if you don't use ViewHolder the solution is the same that I've suggested in this answer. You should adjust styles in getView method.

Comment: Thank u sir, I am fresher I don't know how can I used View holder on this so can you send me some example of these or link which I can read or implemented on our code. Thank you again